# read csv file with java poi version 2

Tags: java, csv

I am reading csv file using java library poi version 2
but I am getting error

```
"Invalid header signature; read 1688935826934608, expected -2226271756974174256"
```

Comment: check this it might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677925/invalid-header-signature-ioexception-with-apache-poi-on-excel-document

Answer (score 1):

I got the fix.
It was simple comma separation buffered reading.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

one of the reason for this error :
you must save the file as `.csv` instead of `.xls` if you are reading a `CSV` file