# Unable to read the excel file using Apache POI - getting exception

Tags: java, excel

Please find the Apache POI java code to read the .xls file.

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

            //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
```

while reading the .xls file using Java Apache POI, I am getting the below error in the Java Console.

**java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x6C6D783F3CBFBBEF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document**

I am able to manually open the excel file without any issues. Do we have the solution to overcome this. I'm completely out of ideas so any help/pointers are greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid header signature; IOException with Apache POI on excel document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677925/invalid-header-signature-ioexception-with-apache-poi-on-excel-document)

Comment: Please do not link with the questions which does not have any proper answer. have already searched these links and I am posting this

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(yourpath+"/WebContent/ProductUpload.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
        int numberOfSheets = workbook.getNumberOfSheets();

        for(int i=0; i < numberOfSheets; i++){

            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
                Iterator ite = sheet.rowIterator();
                while(ite.hasNext()){
                    Row row = (Row)ite.next();
                        Iterator<org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell> cite = row.cellIterator();
                        while(cite.hasNext()){
                            org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell cell = cite.next();

                            }

                }
        }
```

Comment: In your case use HSSFWorkbook

Comment: The above code is not working for the issue I mentioned. Could you please suggest where to add the below code you suggested few mins back Gokul?     response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");

Comment: The above code i have sanded  you is fully tested .... it should work. For .xls you only have to use HSSFWorkbook and HSSFSheet where i have used XSSFWorkbook and XSSFSheet.

Comment: Otherwise try this - > Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(new File("/path"));